# vs2010 cannot build NaCl example code on NaCl64 platform, but can bulid on PPAPI platform

Tags: google-nativeclient

When I build and run **NaCl** example code on **PPAPI** platform, it will be ok. But when I change the platform from **PPAPI** to **NaCl64**, vs2010 shows that it cannot find C++ standard library(eg. ***Error:cannot open source file “string.h”***). Additionally, l have install the **vs_addin** plugin in the vs2010. I guess the configuration has some problem, maybe the library has not been included. But I used default configuration and have done nothing to it, I only follow the steps given in google chrome development tutorial.

Comment: Did you check what the INCLUDE directories in your project property pages specify?